# What happened to the other three wizards after Sauron's defeat?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, istari

Concerning the wizards, *The Silmarilion* states:

> it was said
> among the Elves that they were messengers sent by the Lords of the West to
> contest the power of Sauron

We know from *The Return of the King* that Gandalf went with the ring-bearers into the West:

> ‘Yes, I am coming,’ said Frodo. ‘The Ring-bearers should go together.’
>
> ‘Where are you going, Master?’ cried Sam, though at last he understood what was happening.
>
> ‘To the Havens, Sam,’ said Frodo.

But Radagast and the other two were still in Middle-earth, as far as I know, from *The Hobbit*, *The Lord of the Rings*, and *The Silmarilion*. Is there something else mentioned elsewhere in the legendarium about what happened with the remaining Istari now that their purpose in Middle-earth was fulfilled?

EDIT: [A proposed answer for two of them](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14852/is-there-any-canonical-reference-to-the-fate-of-the-blue-wizards-alatar-and-pal), but it still leaves out the question of Radagast's fate.

Additional edit: [Radagast's fate](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/67711/153074) also has an answer.

Comment: They exploded, probably.

Comment: @A.Steer, almost. It seems contradictory, in that the accepted answer has the two in the east either making cults afterward or successfully helped defeat Sauron, and then ???. And it doesn't answer about Radagast.

Comment: An answer about radergast is here https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/67711/153074

Comment: Yes, thank you, between the two of them, I think that is as close to an answer as I will get. I did search this site before posting, but it seems your searches were better than mine. :)

Comment: I decided to reopen this, based on the question being a combination of the questions which provide an answer, and reviewing other questions marked as duplicates. This question has **answers** in other questions, but isn't a duplicate of another question in itself that I have seen.

Comment: @MichaelFoster If there is more than one question this is duplicate of we can link all of them.

Comment: I added both linked questions with edits to my original question.

Comment: The question can be closed as a duplicate of more than one other question.

Comment: I lack the reputation; perhaps someone else can add https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/67711/153074 as a second duplicate?

Comment: OK, yes, I guess I misspoke (miswrote?). I undeleted the message, but yes, it ought to be closed. And @chepner, I already have that link in my edited question.

Comment: Yes, I just included in my comment to be precise about which question to add.